# Can JMeter test popup windows?

Tags: jmeter

My application uses the popup windows. These popup windows contain normal HTML code.

The first browser window contains the general application information. If the user adds the client id in the first browser window and pushes the search button then the second browser popup window opens. So the first browser sends the HTTP POST command and the network log of the first window shows response of the POST command. The second window contains the detailed information about the client.

The JMeter script recorder can record all the HTTP requests from the first and second windows.

But when I run the JMeter script, it seems that the JMeter can't handle correctly the second window. For example the JMeter log contains only response of the HTTP POST command which is same as in the first browser window when doing manual testing. The HTTP POST response which in the manual testing goes to the second window isn't in the log file.

Is the JMeter test running supporting the popup windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter knows nothing about "popup windows", JMeter acts on [protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP), if opening the "popup" window triggers a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - JMeter will record it and try to replay it.

If opening the "popup window" doesn't generate a HTTP Request - it means that everything is happening on the client (browser) side only and the server is not involved into it. So you will not be able to simulate the behaviour using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

If you need to test the opening of the popup window in the browser you will need to consider switching to browser automation tools, the most popular is [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). There is also [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) which provides JMeter integration with Selenium